# Low frequency Pierce oscillator with transistor

Tags: transistors, amplifier, frequency, oscillator

I am trying to built an oscillator at low frequeny (32768 Hz). After some research i have chosen to build a pierce oscillator. 
Here is my schematics : discard

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjE7MA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have tested the amplifier with a function generator producing 32Khz and it worked well, i have observed a gain of approximatively 3.7. 
The load capacitance of the cristal is about 12.5pF. 
I am not seeing any oscillation at the collector. Any idea about what could be wrong in my setup ?

Thanks !

Comment: Your diagram appears wrong. Hopefully this is not the same as your circuit. | The xtal is short circuited by a wire. Presumably the LH end of xtal should connect to Q1 collector.  | R1 = 3.2 Ohm - should that be 3.2 k  Ohm??? | Gain is approx R1 / (R2 + 26/Ic_ma) . For R1 = 3K2 gain is ~~~ 7.  | Vb~= 1.7V. So Ie ~= (1.7-0.6)/470 ~= 2 mA. VR1 = VR2 x R1/R2 = 1.1 x 3k2/470r = 7.5V. Vce ~+ 12-1.1-7.5 = 3.4V so transistor is not hard on (which is good)

Comment: Oh yes my bad, that the first i use the schematics editor, the LH of the xtal is connected to the collector. Yes R1 is 3.2K. Thanks a lot
@Russel : I have carrefully designed the amplifier part (that the first timefor me ^^)

Answer (score 1):

The crystal + 2 caps form a PI network:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwtcOn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Lets examine the loop gain and loop phaseshift; here in Signal Chain Explorer, the XTAL model is embedded as Z(feedback) of the Inverting OpAmp stage; crystal inductance is 58.9766 Henry; capacitance series/resonance is 0.8pf; the plate-to-plate capacitance is also 0.8pF; Rloss is 1Kohm.

I reduced the two capacitors of the PI network, here before and after the OpAmp, from 22pF to 4.7pF. I've read the low frequency oscillators *need* small capacitors, so the energy is not shorted to GND.

Key point is the gain and bandwidth of the OpAmp. With gain of 10dB (3.16x), shown in the far right BODE, the gain is barely above 0dB.

In contrast, examine the 40dB gain, flat to 100KHz, and see a healthy peak (30+dB gain) at the correct frequency.

Does the value of R4 (in the schematic) matter? Lets examine that next.

[image]

Comment: Nice! Can you send me your simulation? Question : are they the bode diagrams for the closed loop ? What is the parameter whose value is changing for the three first left diagrams ?

Comment: @ Nicolas The changing param is the UnityGain Bandwidth of the opamp. Leftmost sim has 40dB gain, with rolloff at 1KHz (for a 32KHz oscillagtor). Left-1 sim has 40dB gain, rolloff at 10KHz (for a 32KHz oscillator). Left-2 sim (which shows the snappy phase changes, desirable for accurate oscillation) has 40dB gain, rolloff at 100KHz.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a Pierce oscillator because there is no feedback. A typical scheme, where R1 is feedback:

[image]

Comment: The wire from lh end of crystal on his diagram should go to collector. The cct is then similar to yours.  His R1 is vastly too low - which may be a typo.

Comment: How do i choose the value of R1 of the above diagram ? 1MOhm ?

Comment: R1 and C1 provide a phase delay of 65 °([link](http://www.next.gr/circuits/crystal-oscillator-discreet-pierce-oscillator-l32460.html)) to the feedback signal.

Comment: Another example [link](http://www.next.gr/oscillators/pierce/1mhz-pierce-oscillators-l13239.html). With a value of components.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Actually, OPs R4 was too low (though he fixed that in edit), his R1 is still entirely nonexistant (straight trace from XTAL to collector, no resistor)

Comment: @Nicolas FYI: you are also missing D1 and C3 (not labelled--parallel to R5) from this diagram.

Comment: @Nicolas, 1MOhm too much.

Comment: Yeah I think so. I am not really confortable with what it is said about the phase shift introduced by the caps around the crystal : each of the two low pass filters at the resonance frequency of the quartz can only produce a phase shift of 45 degrees each before we reach the frequency region where the attenuation is to high, so how is it supposed to produce a phase shift of 180 ? I miss sthg. 
So I think that i would use a configuration with three low pass filter and a buffer as suggested in the second link. DS :http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2048263.pdf?_ga=1.33033149.248849463.1491316631

Comment: @Nicolas, A single RC network will provide 90 degrees in the extreme. Why 45 degrees? A single LC network will provide 180 degrees in the extreme. The crystal, in this case, acts as inductance.

Comment: @RobhercKV5ROB When I 1st looked his R4 was 24k and still is. He has added a series diode as per Utu's answer which raises base voltage. BUT with R3 R4 = 150k 24k Vb is 24/(24+150) x 12 = =1.66V which gives about 1V on R5 which seems reasonable. So I'm not sure that it was "too small" but larger should also be OK. RM - once ZL1ANC.